# What would be Earth's temperature under a very efficiente greenhouse atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atmospheric-science, meteorology

Assume that Earth has an atmosphere made out of a very efficient greenhouse gas (e.g. a very, very thick wator vapor atmosphere).

1. In that case, what would be the surface temperature (or the temperature of the atmosphere) of Earth? Would it approach a maximum value?

My intuition tells me that all around the Earth the temperature must settle at $\approx 394 K$, because the Sun flux at the Earth distance corresponds to a temperature of $T_{E}=(K_S/\sigma)^{1/4}\approx394 K = 120 C$, where $K_S$ is the solar constant at Earth's distance. In that sence $394 K$ must represent an upper limit and crossing it feels in my intutition like breaking the thermodynamical law that heat can flow only from a hotter body to a colder body.

2. Will the Earth temperature indeed approach some limit? By what factors would the upper limit be determined?
3. Would then the perfect green house atmosphere act also like a perfect heat distributor all around the surface, including the dark side?

Comment: You can't do an energy balance on the earth if you don't permit the earth to radiate energy to outer space.  This means that your question can't be answered.

Comment: The answer depends on how close to perfect you mean. Would an answer based on an atmosphere like Venus help you? There is a lot of $CO_2$ in Venus' atmosphere, which makes it a lot better green house gas than Earth's atmosphere. It make Venus a lot hotter than Earth would be in Venus' orbit.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is unanswerable as written.

Comment: Your planet is too hot. The earth absorbs like a disc and radiates like a sphere (so a factor of 4 is missing), and the albedo is around 33%. The resulting temperature is the temperature of the top 1-optical depth $\tau$ of the atmosphere, and the surface temp depends on how many $\tau$'s are above it.

Comment: @DavidWhite thanks, I correct my question, so it can be physically answerable

Comment: @mmesser314 Yes, I was thinking into this direction, but wondering - what is the upper limit a planets temperature can reach if it has an almost perfect greenhouse atmosphere

Comment: @JEB thanks for pointing out! I neglected the geometrical factor of 4, because I had in mind the calculation not for a sphere (like the Earth), but for any small surface pointed perpendicular to the incoming Sun flux. The value that I provide agrees quite well with the hottest temperatures measured at points on the Moon's equator. In that sense, not the whole Earth can get 394K, but this is the highest temperature a surface on the Earth/Moon can be heated up to by the Sun. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DavidHammen It is more constructive to point out to someone what makes his question not answerable, so that he can edit it, instead of punishing him by closing the question

Comment: Still not answerable. There is no such thing as an "almost" perfect greenhouse, except maybe a black hole. Since we are into hypothetical greenhouses, in what way is this greenhouse flawed? Is black-body radiation permitted?

Comment: The temperature of any object arises from an energy equilibrium of incoming and emitted radiation flux. In normal circumstances: the hotter an object becomes the more radiation it is emitting. In normal circumstances objects reach an equilibrium temperature. In order to predict a specific *value* for equilibrium temperature it is necessary to have a *formula* for the absorption/emission characteristics of the object; a numerical expression. The word *almost* fails at that. Without data all one can say is: 'An *almost* perfect greenhouse will become *very* hot', which is totally unhelpful.

Comment: So a better question would be what makes an atmosphere a good greenhouse atmosphere, and how hot would Earth be under the best such atmosphere? Things like absorption spectrum and thickness of the atmosphere matter.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Yes, black-body radiation is permitted. I get your extreme example with the blackhole. I want the assume the case of a very effective green house gas, that is still physically reasonable, so I changed the question to treat the green house as water vapor